# Creating a welcome page for a facebook page

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-page

since facebook changed the whole fbml, apps and fan page stuff I've got a bit confused.

I need to make a welcome page (tab) for users who has not liked the fan page and a start page for users who have liked the fan page.

What should I use; apps, fbml, iframe etc.? How/where should I start?

Just need someone to point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now you can still use the FBML tab

http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=4949752878

Add it to your page, type in some code, make it a tab on your page and select it as the default landing page (in your page settings panel)